# What do i insert for "app domains" for an application deployed onto heroku

Tags: facebook, heroku

I currently have an application deployed onto `heroku`.

This is the link: https://pacific-badlands-21803.herokuapp.com/

Facebook registration is implemented but it is not working because i do not know what to specify as the `app domain` on my application console on facebook.

Any help on what i should be inserting into `app domain`

Comment: Well the domain/ host name part of the URL you have just shown …

Answer (score 0):

Enter your Site URL and hit save.
https://pacific-badlands-21803.herokuapp.com/
Or have you changed a URL's of an existing App?

Can you please recheck the settings of your APP in this page?

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Select the correct App and click in the edit button;

Check the URLs & paths are correctly entered and are pointing to the site where you have installed Ultimate Facebook plugin.